# CURL in php to C# .Net

Tags: c#, php, curl

I'm trying to convert CURL in PHP to C #, the call in PHP is successful, when making the call in C #, it returns a 401 error.

C# that produces an `unauthorized error (401)`:

```
var data = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new { amount = "29.07" });
string url = "https://devapice.vnforapps.com/api.ecommerce/api/v1/ecommerce/token/101340XXX";

HttpWebRequest q = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
q.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);
q.PreAuthenticate = true;
q.Method = "POST";
q.ContentType = "application/json";
q.Headers.Add("VisaNet-Session-Key", new Guid().ToString());

q.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("XXXAILCA2WW4PT2QHXXX", "XXXi0ZVrIcmtp8jVhCYSn0H9KcprJHVOTBKvKXXX");
byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

q.ContentLength = buffer.Length;

using (Stream stream = q.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}

HttpWebResponse reps = q.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
Console.Write(reps.ToString());
```

Working PHP version:

```
$sessionToken = getGUID();
$url = "https://devapice.vnforapps.com/api.ecommerce/api/v1/ecommerce/token/1480XXXXX";
$header = array("Content-Type: application/json","VisaNet-Session-Key: $sessionToken");
    $request_body="{
        \"amount\":1.00
    }";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "XXXAILCA2WW4PT2QHXXX:XXXa4Zg3ltemrcNG7pLergqwwGlYJH+rahejFXXX");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request_body);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$json = json_decode($response);
$dato = $json->sessionKey;

    function getGUID(){
        if (function_exists('com_create_guid')){
            return com_create_guid();
        }else{
            mt_srand((double)microtime()*10000);//optional for php 4.2.0 and up.
            $charid = strtoupper(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)));
            $hyphen = chr(45);// "-"
            $uuid = chr(123)// "{"
                .substr($charid, 0, 8).$hyphen
                .substr($charid, 8, 4).$hyphen
                .substr($charid,12, 4).$hyphen
                .substr($charid,16, 4).$hyphen
                .substr($charid,20,12).$hyphen
                .chr(125);// "}"
            $uuid = substr($uuid, 1, 36);
            return $uuid;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Activate the tracing for the webrequest add this config in your app.config
And compare this with the php request

```
<system.diagnostics>

  <trace autoflush="true" />

  <sources>
    <source name="System.Net" maxdatasize="1024">
      <listeners>
        <add name="MyTraceFile"/>
        <add name="MyConsole"/>
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>

  <sharedListeners>
    <add name="MyTraceFile" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="System.Net.trace.log" />
    <add name="MyConsole" type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener" />
  </sharedListeners>

  <switches>
    <add name="System.Net" value="Information" />
  </switches>
</system.diagnostics>
```

More Information you can found on this [blog](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.co.at/2012/07/tracing-systemnet-to-debug-http-clients.html)